# Implementing Bar Code Scanner in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode-scanner

I want to implement the barcode scanner, I tried using the sample code [from this link](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) .

This will scan the barcode, but I want to show the redline in the screen itself, it means, I want to show the redline whenever I start to scan the barcode.

Is it possible to show the red line inside the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are some good API for bar code scanning :

[RMScannerView](https://github.com/iRareMedia/RMScannerView)

[ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

[MTBBarcodeScanner](https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner)

[ZBar bar code reader](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)

[shopsavvy](http://shopsavvy.com/developers/)

[Softek Barcode Reader SDK](http://www.bardecode.com/en1/app/mobilesdk/)

[Scandit Barcode Scanner (not free)](http://docs.scandit.com/stable/ios/)

Below is the code snippetif you use ZBar API :

```
ZBarReaderController *reader = [ZBarReaderController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;

    //... code to get image

CGImageRef imgCG = image.CGImage;


id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [reader scanImage:imgCG];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;
resultText.text = symbol.data;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks @Ketan p , where i have to add these code snippet into my project ??

Comment: @kavi you can add on any button where you want to scan barcode image.. Please refer link http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html It will help you to implement.

Comment: @kavi you can tick as answer if it helps you regarding Barcode Scanning SDK. If you tick as answer it will help other SO user as well.